# TypeScript calling methods on class inside jquery function scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, typescript

I have the below TypeScript class.

```
export class BrandViewModel {

        private _items = ko.observableArray();

        public Add(id: number, name: string, active: boolean) : void {
            this._items.push(new BrandItem(this, id, name, active));
        }

        public Get() : void  {
            $.get("/api/brand", function(items) {
                $.each(items, function (i, item) {
                        this.Add(item.Id, item.Name, item.Active);
                    });
            }, "json");
        }
}
```

The resulting javascript for the `Get` method is:

```
    BrandViewModel.prototype.Get = function () {
        $.get("/api/brand", function (items) {
            $.each(items, function (i, item) {
                this.Add(item.Id, item.Name, item.Active);
            });
        }, "json");
    };
```

I have seen in the `TypeScript` documentation that I can do this:

```
    public Get() : void  {
        $.get("/api/brand", () => function(items) {
            $.each(items, function (i, item) {
                    this.Add(item.Id, item.Name, item.Active);
                });
        }, "json");
    }
```

Which results in the below, where `_this` is now a reference to the `BrandViewModel` instance but the `this` inside the jquery `.each` function is not changed to `_this` as I might expect:

```
    BrandViewModel.prototype.Get = function () {
        var _this = this;
        $.get("/api/brand", function () {
            return function (items) {
                $.each(items, function (i, item) {
                    this.Add(item.Id, item.Name, item.Active);
                });
            };
        }, "json");
    };
```

Instead I have done the below in `TypeScript`:

```
    public Get(): void {
        var _this = this;
        $.get("/api/brand", function(items) {
            $.each(items, function (i, item) {
                    _this.Add(item.Id, item.Name, item.Active);
                });
        }, "json");
    }
```

which gives me the result I wanted:

```
    BrandViewModel.prototype.Get = function () {
        var _this = this;
        $.get("/api/brand", function (items) {
            $.each(items, function (i, item) {
                _this.Add(item.Id, item.Name, item.Active);
            });
        }, "json");
    };
```

**Does anyone know a more appropriate way to do this?**

Comment: can you help me about my demo.I don't know why it can not run https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834032/uncaught-typeerror-this-delete-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this:

```
    public Get() : void  {
        $.get("/api/brand", (items) => {
            $.each(items, (i, item) => {
                    this.Add(item.Id, item.Name, item.Active);
                });
        }, "json");
    }
```

Which generates:

```
    BrandViewModel.prototype.Get = function () {
        var _this = this;
        $.get("/api/brand", function (items) {
            $.each(items, function (i, item) {
                _this.Add(item.Id, item.Name, item.Active);
            });
        }, "json");
    };
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you. Any chance of a bit of explanation on how that works as it does? i.e. knows to place the `_this` outside of both functions?

Comment: That gets generated when you use the fat arrow notation I.e. ()=>{}

Comment: @basarat what I am asking though is the fat arrow notation is being used twice and nested.. how does `_this` get put in the correct place.

Comment: @Pricey typescript will generate it at the top of a fat arrow chain. If you have a `function()` in between then that chain will break.

Answer (score 0):

Consistent with [ECMAScript 6 arrow functions](http://tc39wiki.calculist.org/es6/arrow-functions/), TypeScript lexically binds this when using =>.