# Uncaught TypeError: this.delete is not a function

Tags: jquery, typescript

```
import * as React from "react";
import $ = require("jquery");


export class Hello extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
public delete() {
    console.log("delete");
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/delete",
        xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}
    }).done((data: any): void => {
        console.log("delete data:" + data);
    }).fail((jqXHR: any): void => {
        console.log("delete faildata: " + jqXHR.status);
    });
}


public save() {
    console.log("save");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/save",
        dataType: "text",
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}
    }).done((data: any): void => {
        console.log("data:" + data);
        {this.delete()}
    }).fail((jqXHR: any): void => {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log("faildata: " + jqXHR.status);
    });
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.delete}>delete</button>
            <button onClick={this.save}>save</button>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

update the code, click save ,if the operate done . start to delete data ,
but now it appears error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUMeo.png)
Hello.tsx:36 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined, I have seen the example [TypeScript calling methods on class inside jquery function scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618350/typescript-calling-methods-on-class-inside-jquery-function-scope), i don't konw why that can run?

Comment: `this` within the `done()` and `fail()` handlers will not refer to whatever outer scope you're expecting it to. Given your code sample, you don't even appear to need the `this` reference at all.

Comment: upadte my code ,can you help me ?

Comment: Not really, as you still haven't explained what you're expecting `this` to be a reference to

Comment: i have known where i am wrong ,thank you very much! i can't use this here

Comment: you don't need the `{}` on `{this.delete()}` you are already using the fat arrow notation `() =>` look at the javascript that is generated to understand what _this is.

Comment: @Pricey I don't know whether your response is ok, i will try!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
private save() {
    console.log("save");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/save",
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}
    }).done((function (data) {
        console.log("data:" + data);
        this.delete();
    }).bind(this)).fail((function (jqXHR:any) {
        console.log("faildata: "+jqXHR.status)
        this.delete();
    }).bind(this));
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work ,Hello.tsx:45 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined